# Android: My app automatically restarted after it crashed, weird

Tags: android

When my app crashed, it would automatically restart once, and only once.
To completely shut it down, I had to manually kill the process by using of task manager.
I've no idea what happened...
Anyone could help? thx.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the bugs so it doesn't crash?

Other than that, I don't know. Some example code might help. If you add some example of where it crashes and the few lines called before and after the crash, I may be able to give a real answer. If so, leave a comment on my answer and I'll get back to you.

And maybe Android is holding a reference to the Activity because it was not properly shut down, so it opens it back up as it's the reference at the top of the stack? That's kind of just a guess, though.

Comment: I'm wondering why it automatically restarted, not why it crashed. In my activity, I started a service and then binded to that service. I'm guessing the service lifecycle caused this. thx.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. a started service gets longer lifecycle, and system may try to resume it if memory was enough.

Comment: Okay, yeah that would make since. I was asking for the lines of code to see if maybe there was some unresolved call or something that maybe didn't finish when it crashed. The binding does make it make perfect since, though.